# How set the opacity/alpha of an image using OpenGL ES 2.0 and GLKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I have create function with OpenGL ES 2.0 and GLKit.

I have used GLKBaseEffect for draw GLKTextureInfo and GLKTextureLoader for load PNG file on GLKTextureInfo. (heart.png)

Now, I want to set the opacity of the PNG image. This may sound simple, but I have no idea how I can change the opacity...

[image]